# Multiple items in a single column

Tags: r, csv

One of the columns in my data is multiple-choice data that refer to the UN Sustainable Development Goals that are applicable to each row. The Column looks like this, with multiple comma-separated lists of SDGs for each row:

```
 SDGs
 5,6,7,13,17
 7,9,17
 3,4,7,11
 3,4,6,7,11
 4,5,7,14
 4,5,6,11,13
 3,17
```

I'd like to tabulate the overall occurrence of each SDG as well as cross-tabulate it with other columns (such as region, country etc). How can I unpack this into a form that I can use to create tables and cross tables? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I have only included first two rows of your dataset. Is this what you are looking for? If not please share sample dataset and desired output -

```
library(tidyr)
df <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "B"), SDGs = c(" 5,6,7,13,17", 
                                                     " 7,9,17")),
                .Names = c("Country", "SDGs"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

#   Country         SDGs
# 1       A  5,6,7,13,17
# 2       B       7,9,17

df <- separate_rows(df, SDGs, sep = ",")

#    Country SDGs
# 1        A    5
# 2        A    6
# 3        A    7
# 4        A   13
# 5        A   17
# 6        B    7
# 7        B    9
# 8        B   17
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is exactly what I had wanted.

Comment: Happy to help! Please consider marking this answer as correct using the tick mark at top left of this answer.